# Xamarin Forms: Toasts.Forms.Plugin error

Tags: c#, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms, toast

I used [Toasts.Forms.Plugin](https://github.com/EgorBo/Toasts.Forms.Plugin) by EgorBo in a project and it was working fine. I added it in a new project but I can't find **ToastNotification** or **IToastNotification** and the toast doesn't appear.

My Xamarin.Forms version is 2.3.2.127 and your component is 1.0.1

I tried to add this code in the iOS *AppDelegate.cs*

```
DependencyService.Register<Plugin.Toasts.CrossToasts>();
Plugin.Toasts.ToastsImplementation.Init();
```

but obviously it doesn't work. I tried to change my static method but *IToasts* it doesn't work.

```
public static async Task ShowToast(ToastNotificationType type, 
                                   string title, string description) {
    var notificator = DependencyService.Get<Plugin.Toasts.Abstractions.IToasts>();
    if (notificator != null) {
        bool tapped = await notificator.Notify(type, title, description, 
                                               TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2));
    }
}
```

Original code in AppDelegate.cs

```
DependencyService.Register<ToastNotificatorImplementation>();
ToastNotificatorImplementation.Init();
```

Original code in my class

```
public static async void ShowToast(ToastNotificationType type, string title, 
                                   string description) {
    var notificator = DependencyService.Get<IToastNotificator>();
    if (notificator != null) {
        bool tapped = await notificator.Notify(type, title, description, 
                                               TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2));
    }
}
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Version 3 and higher technically only supports .NET standard 1.1 and higher. The recommended approach is to stay on 2.0.4 if you havent upgraded to .NET standard.